# Remote logging for Android Beta

Tags: android, logging, testflight

Is there a tool that does android remote logging for Android apps, kinda like Testflight's for [IOs](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/840057-how-do-i-implement-remote-logging-) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [Deploy Gate](https://deploygate.com) very helpful for me.

You can do remote loggin and also trac application launches, crash reports.

Comment: From their homepage: "Enable Remote LogCat Additional permission required
Android 4.1 or higher On the devices running Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean) or higher, Remote LogCat works without adding the permission. However, for security reasons, you can only see the log produced by your app process." So it seems that they do not support older versions of android for Remote Logging.

Comment: Well, it depends on your use case. I use Deploy Gate for beta versions which have: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />`.

Comment: does it work for android 2.3?

Comment: I actually use it on android 4.0 w/o any problems. So I am a little bit confused. I am not sure about android 2.3. But I bet it would work . I think your qoutation form first comment is only about permissions.

Comment: Thanks for it! I've tried on android 2.3, and everything works amazingly. They have both remote logcat and remote logging.

Answer (score 2):

Also, TestFlight is just about to launch support for Android: https://testflightapp.com/android/ so you might want to sign up to be informed when they do.

Comment: I tried getting to testfilght beta, no email so far. And I'm not sure they do remote logging.

Comment: Its open now. Check it out.

Comment: RIP TestFlight for Android

Answer (score 1):

I've used ACRA in my projects with great success.  You can find that at: http://acra.ch/  It works great when used in the debugging process, but I remove it before publishing.

It can be configured to automatically send a report on a crash, if the app enters a particular state, via a trigger (like a button a user could press) or what have you.  For my purposes, I usually have it trigger on a crash, and I add an option to the menu to send a Force Debug Report if the tester feels like the app is doing something odd, but isn't crashing.